# How to update onSignalStrength (Signal Strength)

Tags: android, phone-state-listener, signal-strength

I have developed an app that listens signals strength. I used *Phone State Listener* for listening **onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength)**. SignalStrength is updated by phone. However, I want to update the signalStrength frequently. How to changes signal strength updating period in android programmability?

Answer (score 0):

Android does not check this level more often to provide to the standard APIs. There is no option to poll this values. You would have to store the last value received through `onSignalStrengthsChanged()` and return the last value when your application needs it (if the faster polling rate is your goal).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My problem is not related polling rate. I developed an app for vieweing signal strength. But I observed that when I open  `the phone own signal strength viewer` (Settings/About Phone/State), signal strength is updated frequently. But when I run my app only, the signal strength is not updated frequently. I understand if the phone own signal viewer is open, then signal strength is updated frequently.Otherwise, signal strength is updated at a certain time interval. I ask how to changes updating time interval. @Jonas Köritz

Comment: What device are you using? My signal strength is not updating frequently in the settings view.

Comment: I have used Samsung Galaxy j7 @ Jonas Köritz.

Comment: Maybe Samsungs settings app is different. I dont think this is possible in a portable way.

Comment: Thanks.@Jonas Köritz